# wordpress sydney theme shrink header upon scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress-theming

I am trying to shrink the header after scrolling. I am working on the child theme.

Here is a screen shot of how the header looks at the top of the page
[image]

This is how it looks when scrolled down a little

[image]

This is how I want it to look upon scrolling

[image]

I added this css to the child theme to make the logo bigger:

```
.site-logo{
    max-height:200px;
 }
```

I want the max-height to shrink to 100px upon scrolling. I dont know how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I added this css and it worked perfectly.

```
 .site-logo {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
 .float-header .site-logo {
    max-height: 100px;
  }
```

I found the solution to my problem from one of the questions posted on aThemes support page.